# Extracting filesnames in bash with regex

Tags: regex, bash, awk

Can please someone help me to set up a regular expression.

I have a large LaTeX3 TeXDoc file.  LaTeX3 TeXDoc defines the macro `\TestFiles{}`, which should be used, to list the names of files, which itself should be used as an unit tests.  You can name more than one file between the braces.  So `\TestFiles{foo-bar}` and `\TestFiles{foo-bar, bar+baz,foo_bar_baz}` are syntactical correct use cases for this macro.

I would like to write a bash script, to extract all the uni test files, named in the `\TestFiles{}` macros, to compile them with `pdflatex` and check, if `pdflatex` will be able to produce an output file successfully.

I have something like this in my script:

```sh
function get_filenames () {
  ## This regex works but is not sensible enough
  # regex='\\TestFiles{(.*)}'
  ## This works also, but is again not precise enough
  regex='\\TestFiles{([0-9a-zA-Z+-_, ]*)}'
  ## This should give more than one matching group 
  ## (separated by ", " or ","), but this regex doesn't 
  ## work.  I have no idea why or how to modify, to get 
  ## it working
  
  while read -r line ; do
    if [[ $line =~ $regex ]] ; then
      i=1
        while [ $i -le 3 ]; do
          echo "Match $i: \"${BASH_REMATCH[$i]}\""
          i=$(( i + 1 ))
        done
      echo
    fi
  done < mystyle.dtx
}
```

Here is an excerpt of the DTX file

```latex
\TestFiles{foo-bar}

\TestFiles{foo-bar, bar+baz,foo_bar_baz}
```

(You can store this as mystyle.dtx, in order to reproduce the next example.)

Using the above noted examples, my script gives me the following results:

```sh
get_filenames
Match 1: "foo-bar"
Match 2: ""
Match 3: ""

Match 1: "foo-bar, bar+baz,foo_bar_baz"
Match 2: ""
Match 3: ""
```

I wasn't able, to modify my `regex` expression, to split the content of the last `\TestFiles{foo-bar, bar+baz,foo_bar_baz}` example into three matching results.

I tried a regular expression like this `regex='\\TestFiles{([[:alnum:]+-_]*)[,]+[ ]*}'`.  I thought the `[:alnum:]+-_]*` would match the filenames.  As far as I understand regular expressions, the `(...)` should form a group, that should be listed afterwards in the bash array `BASH_REMATCH[$i]`.

The part `[,]+` should reflect that every file name must be separated by at least one comma.  Between the filenames there might be some white space, so something like `[[:space:]]*` or at least `[ ]*` should represent this.  The quantifier `*` means any repetition, ranging from 0 to ..., while `+` should at least appear one or more times.

But that regular expression did not work at all, if had no matching results.

How must `regex` be defined, to store each filenames as a matching group?  I am searching for the correct regular expression, to get this result:

```sh
get_filenames
Match 1: "foo-bar"
Match 2: ""
Match 3: ""

Match 1: "foo-bar"
Match 2: "bar+baz"
Match 3: "foo_bar_baz"
```

EDIT: in my real world files, there may be (and are) more than tree test files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a regex bracket expression, `+-_` will match any character between "+" and "_" (in the current locale's collating order) -- I'm pretty sure this isn't what you want. To include the single character "-" in the set, put it either at the beginning or end of the list (where it can't be taken as indicating a range), e.g. `[-[:alnum:]+_]` or `[[:alnum:]+_-]`

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you for your kind comment.  Yes, I didn't want that range, it was an accident, due to not being well trained in REGEX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
## This should give more than one matching group
regex='\\TestFiles{([0-9a-zA-Z+-_, ]*)}'
```

> The element of BASH_REMATCH with index n is the portion of the string matching the nth parenthesized subexpression.

Your regex only has 1 *"parenthesized subexpression"* - which is why everything ends up in `BASH_REMATCH[1]`

```
$ regex='\\TestFiles{([0-9a-zA-Z+-_, ]*)}'
$ [[ $line =~ $regex ]]
$ declare -p BASH_REMATCH
declare -a BASH_REMATCH=(
    [0]="\\TestFiles{foo-bar, bar+baz,foo_bar_baz}" 
    [1]="foo-bar, bar+baz,foo_bar_baz"
)
```

As you're trying to match an unknown number of filenames you would have to *"dynamically"* create your regex so it contains the needed amount of groups.

```
$ regex='\\TestFiles{([^, }]+)([,}] ?)'
$ [[ $line =~ $regex ]]
$ declare -p BASH_REMATCH
declare -a BASH_REMATCH=(
    [0]="\\TestFiles{foo-bar, " 
    [1]="foo-bar" 
    [2]=", "
)
```

Add another group and see if it still matches:

```
$ regex+='([^, }]+)([,}] ?)'
$ [[ $line =~ $regex ]]
$ declare -p BASH_REMATCH
declare -a BASH_REMATCH=(
    [0]="\\TestFiles{foo-bar, bar+baz," 
    [1]="foo-bar" 
    [2]=", " 
    [3]="bar+baz" 
    [4]=","
)
```

You could keep looping until the regex no longer matches - or perhaps a simpler approach would be to count the number of `,` characters on the line.

```
regex='\\TestFiles{([^, }]+)([,}] ?)'
line='\TestFiles{foo-bar, bar+baz,foo_bar_baz}'
commas=${line//[!,]}

for ((i=0; i<${#commas}; i++))
do
    regex+='([^, }]+)([,}] ?)'
done

[[ $line =~ $regex ]]
```

Which results in:

```
$ declare -p BASH_REMATCH
declare -a BASH_REMATCH=(
    [0]="\\TestFiles{foo-bar, bar+baz,foo_bar_baz}" 
    [1]="foo-bar" 
    [2]=", " 
    [3]="bar+baz" 
    [4]="," 
    [5]="foo_bar_baz" 
    [6]="}"
)
```

## Alternative approach using `IFS`

You can set `IFS=', '` and have bash do the splitting for you.

```
line='\TestFiles{foo-bar, bar+baz,foo_bar_baz}'

[[ $line = \\TestFiles{* ]] && {
    # Remove leading '\Testfiles{'
    # Remove trailing }
    line=${line#*{} 
    line=${line%}}

    IFS=', ' read -a filenames <<< "$line"

    declare -p filenames
}
```

```
declare -a filenames=([0]="foo-bar" [1]="bar+baz" [2]="foo_bar_baz}}")
```

Comment: Karl, using IFS is of course possible.  In my case, I am wondering, whats wrong with  my regular expression.

Comment: Well, there's two errors in your regex: non-escaped curly braces (don't know why they works in your working example) and dash in the middle of character class (it has to appear just before closing square bracket or to be escaped)

Comment: Well, actually it works, but dash in the middle of square brackets has to define symbols range

Answer (score 1):

EDIT (without external programs, though it's rather impractical, and tied to exactly three matches)

```
function get_filenames () {
    p='([^, }]*) *,? *'
    regex="\\TestFiles\{$p$p$p"

    while read -r line ; do
        if [[ $line =~ $regex ]] ; then
            i=1
            while [ $i -le 3 ]; do
                echo "Match $i: \"${BASH_REMATCH[$i]}\""
                i=$(( i + 1 ))
            done
            echo
        fi
    done < mystyle.dtx
}
```

If you really need to output exactly three file names (even empty) for each '\TestFiles' row then here's the code.

```
function get_filenames () {
    MAX_FILES_CNT=3
    IFS=$'\n'
    for line in $(grep -oP '\\TestFiles\{\K[^}]*' < mystyle.dtx); do
        filenames=()
        for filename in $(grep -m $MAX_FILES_CNT -oP "[^, ]+" <<< "$line"); do
            filenames+=("$filename")
        done
        i=0
        while [ $i -lt $MAX_FILES_CNT ]; do
            echo "Match $(($i+1)): \"${filenames[i]}\""
            i=$(( i + 1 ))
        done
        echo ""
    done
    unset IFS
}
```

> Match 1: "foo-bar"
>
> Match 2: ""
>
> Match 3: ""
>
> Match 1: "foo-bar"
>
> Match 2: "bar+baz"
>
> Match 3: "foo_bar_baz"

By the way, BASH_REMATCH is no good for this task, cause it captures only last *rematch*. Look

```
[[ "asdf" =~ (.)* ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
```

> asdf f

Also I would recommend to read this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Comment: One of my goals was to prevent calls to other external programs, as you did with enabling `grep`.  But I will read the link and follow its instructions.  Its quite informative.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `set` with `IFS` to split each line into new positional parameters. Assign `$@` to an array so that elements can be accessed by index. Trying this with `$@` directly results in a `bad substitution` error.

get-filenames.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

get_filenames() {
    local IFS=' {},'
    declare -a names

    while read -r line; do
        set -- $line
        names=($@)
        test "${names[0]}" == '\TestFiles' && {
            for i in {1..3}; do
                printf "Match %i: \"%s\"\n" $i ${names[$i]}
            done
        }
        echo
    done < 'mystyle.dtx'
}

get_filenames
```

mystyle.dtx

```
\TestFiles{foo-bar}
\TestFiles{foo-bar, bar+baz,foo_bar_baz}
```

output

```
Match 1: "foo-bar"
Match 2: ""
Match 3: ""

Match 1: "foo-bar"
Match 2: "bar+baz"
Match 3: "foo_bar_baz"
```

Comment: Cole, you solution works, but my question was aimed to get some experience of REGEX, which I am bad in setting up.  Thanks anyways for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting an `awk` script that would do the trick on one or more files.

#### get_filenames.awk

```
/\\TestFiles{[^}]*}/ { # handle only lines matching regex filter
  filesCount = split($0, fileNamesArr, "\\\\TestFiles{[ ]*|[ ]*,[ ]*|[ ]*}"); # parse line to array fileNamesArr
  for (i = 2; i < filesCount; i++) { # read elements 2 --> filesCount - 1
    printf("Match %d in %s: \"%s\"\n", i - 1, FILENAME, fileNamesArr[i]); # format print fileNames
  }
  print"";
}
```

#### test file: input.1.txt

```
some text line 1
\TestFiles{foo-bar0}
some text \TestFiles{foo-bar1, bar+baz1, foo_bar_baz1}
some text \TestFiles{foo-bar2 ,bar+baz2 ,foo_bar_baz2 }
some text \TestFiles{ foo-bar3 , bar+baz3 , foo_bar_baz3 } some text
line 4
```

#### test file: input.2.txt

```
    \TestFiles{file10, file11}
text
text \TestFiles{  file20 } some text
text\TestFiles{file30,file31,file32   }text
text
```

#### testing`get_filenames.awk`

```
awk -f get_filenames.awk input.1.txt input.2.txt

Match 1 in input.1.txt: "foo-bar0"

Match 1 in input.1.txt: "foo-bar1"
Match 2 in input.1.txt: "bar+baz1"
Match 3 in input.1.txt: "foo_bar_baz1"

Match 1 in input.1.txt: "foo-bar2"
Match 2 in input.1.txt: "bar+baz2"
Match 3 in input.1.txt: "foo_bar_baz2"

Match 1 in input.1.txt: "foo-bar3"
Match 2 in input.1.txt: "bar+baz3"
Match 3 in input.1.txt: "foo_bar_baz3"

Match 1 in input.2.txt: "file10"
Match 2 in input.2.txt: "file11"

Match 1 in input.2.txt: "file20"

Match 1 in input.2.txt: "file30"
Match 2 in input.2.txt: "file31"
Match 3 in input.2.txt: "file32"
```

Comment: Another clever solution, thanks.  My intention was to solve this problem with regex and bash alone, avoiding to call external programs like AWK.  Thats why I intentionally did not add the tag `AWK` to the list of tags.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the regular expression you're looking for:

```
(?<=\\TestFiles{.*)([\w\d\-\+_]+)[, }]+
```

You can see it working, modify it and have an explanation on what it does in the following link: https://regex101.com/r/0W8PBi/1

Comment: That's not valid in "extended" regular expression syntax (which, despite the name, is actually pretty basic). You're testing it using the JavaScript flavor of RE syntax, which includes a bunch of extensions that ERE doesn't have. (Note: since bash actually uses the OS's regex library, it may support *some* extensions on *some* OSes.)

Comment: Following the link in your answer, it shows me, that the regex is not valid, as @GordonDavisson also pointed out.